# Show Composition Map $S_3 \to S_4/V$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Consider the subset $V = \{1,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$ of $S_4$.
Let $\pi : S_4 \to S_4/V$ be the quotient map. There is a natural group homomorphism
$\rho : S_3 \to S_4$, which sends a 2-cycle $(i j)$ to $(i j)$, and a 3-cycle $(i j k)$ to
$(i j k)$. Show that the composition map $\pi \rho : S_3 \to S_4/V$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: have you looked at what $V\cap S_3$ is if elements of $S_3$ differ by an element of $V$?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously $\pi \rho$ is a group homomorphism as a composition of group homomorphism. Now prove that this map is surjective, which shouldn't be difficult to conclude just by looking at the cosets of $V$ in $S_4$. Now to prove that the map is injective just prove that $\ker \pi \rho$ is $\{e\}$, which should be easy by looking at which elements are in $\ker \pi$ and which of these elements are in the image of $\rho$.